varibles in __init__() get overlap?
I am using __init__() to storing 2 varibles called self.a, self.b. I want to use these var for tracking changes that may happen. However if i using list instead of int it seem that self.b are now self.a(permanetly) and take change as self.a change too. Could anyone explain to me what happen here?, how to fix this problem?
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [0,0]
        self.b = [0,0]
    def func(self):
        self.a[0] += 1
        print(self.a,self.b,self.a == self.b) #expect return all Flase
        self.b = self.a #<---?
run = A()
for i in range(10):
    run.func()

I try to asign a sub var "B = self.b" and replace "self.b = self.a" with "B = self.a" didn't change any result. So as using "A,B = self.a, self.b" to avoid calling directly.

Are you trying to keep a copy of the previous state of self.a as self.b?  If that is the case, you need to use self.b = self.a.copy().  Otherwise, both a and b reference the same object, so any change to that object will be see by both.

self.b = self.a makes self.b and self.a reference the same list (as you have noticed. If you want to store a copy of self.a in self.b, use self.b = self.a.copy().
